# Importing a csv into R using read.csv in Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, read.table

I have just installed Ubuntu on my computer and I am re-running some codes that previously worked in Windows. I have copied my directories into Ubuntu with all my files.

When I run this line of code to import a database into R, I get the following error:

```
Annot <- read.csv("~/Documents/DATABASES/Functional_Annotations/Salar_2_Annot_light.csv", header = TRUE)
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message: In file(file, "rt") :   cannot open file
'/home/cd46/Documents/DATABASES/Functional_Annotations/Salar_2_Annot_light.csv':
No such file or directory
```

The code is right, hasn't changed since before. In fact if I run:

```
setwd("~/Documents/DATABASES/Functional_Annotations")
```

It works fine and recognize the directory. And the file it there too.

I am not sure what this can be, does anyone have a suggestion? The only thing I have done was to switch over to Ubuntu, so I would imagine the problem would lie there.

Comment: Does it work to `setwd` then just `read.csv` on the filename without the full path?

Comment: What does a `path.expand("~/Documents/DATABASES/Functional_Annotations")` tell you?

Comment: use `ls -l` to check the assigned access rights to the CSV file

Comment: And check whether there is a typo in the file name (Ubuntu file names are case sensitive)...

Answer (score 0):

I have installed the readr package in R 
then simply write this :

df <- read_csv("/your path/file.csv")
And this  work for me and solved the problem.